# "トサカに　くる" meaning

Tags: translation

This is taken from the manga Doraemon - of which I'm sure most people are familiar with so in explaining the context I hope you don't think I'm crazy..

Having eaten a transforming biscuit that turned him into a cockerel, a man complains about a prank phone call he just took:

"だれかの　いたずらだ、　トサカに　くる"

Translating that literally hasn't enabled me to understand the joke. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Japanese the phrase 「頭にくる」 is an idiom used to mean "get angry." 「トサカにくる」 is a slang version of that that emphasizes just how cheesed off you are. トサカ (=鶏冠) is [the red part at the top of a chicken/rooster's head](http://livedoor.blogimg.jp/cyocotomoca/imgs/9/3/93517228.JPG). Notice how it goes up through the head and kind of flares out. Because of how silly the image is, though, you'd use it at a time when a kind of silly playfulness is involved. According to [this site](http://zokugo-dict.com/20to/tosakanikuru.htm) it might refer to the redness of the chicken as blood rushing to your head.

Apparently when you're seriously angry and just *have* to express it through a bodily extremity, you can use 「[怒髪天{どはつてん}を衝{つ}く](http://www.fleapedia.com/%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9/%E3%81%A8/%E3%83%88%E3%82%B5%E3%82%AB%E3%81%AB%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B/)」.

Comment: Very interesting! The last one makes for a particularly intriguing translation. Are they phrases more commonly used to describe ones own anger? I've rarely heard anything besides variations of 怒る.

Comment: Do you really use those expressions yourself?

Comment: @非回答者 No, this answer is based entirely on stuff I found elsewhere. I'm not making any claims here about how common any of these are.

Comment: @非回答者 do you have any other issues with this answer except for (what I assume) the obscurity of the expressions themselves? Does something seem wrong to you?